# Apply .background() to entire WidgetKit complication

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetkit, apple-watch-complication

I'm new to iOS development and I am struggling to make the `.background()` modifier to a view apply to the entire background. My code is as follows, intended to be an apple watch complication:

```
struct DrinkCountComplicationsEntryView : View {
    var entry: SimpleEntry

    var body: some View {
        let theCount = getCount()
        let link = URL(string: "myApp://widgetClick")?
            .appending(queryItems: [URLQueryItem(name: "count", value: String(theCount))])
        ZStack {
            Text("DRINK")
                .offset(x: 0, y: -15)
                .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .semibold))
            Text(String(theCount))
                .font(.title)
                .offset(x: 0, y: 0)
            Text("COUNT")
                .offset(x: 0, y: 15)
                .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .semibold))
        }
        .widgetURL(link)
        .background()
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

I thought having `.ignoresSafeArea()` plus `.background()` would do the trick, but instead it applies the background as a box around the text. It also flashes on refresh. Thoughts?

It also appears completely broken on both Preview and Simulator.

[image]

Comment: I suspect this might have to do with the area content takes. Try adding .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) before the .background()

Comment: I suggest you learn the basics of SwiftUI before building an app. It might be best to go step by step to save a lot of corner cases and misunderstandings. `ZStack` is used to lay views one over the other. So `ZStack { Color.red ..... }` would lay red over what follows after that. There are so many issues with your code. Why are using ZStack for the text? Why do you have variables inside the body? Please learn the basics. Use `ZStack{ Color.red { VStack { Text("a") Text("b") } }`

Comment: Works! Same comment as below - you have any idea how to get rid of the flashing?

Comment: The `ZStack` is necessary to get the desired spacing. I learned it in a tutorial. True, I know very little, but I find by building something I want to build, this is my chance to learn. I've done a few tutorials but this seems to work better for me.

I fixed the flashing by removing the app and reinstalling it. It appears to be an iOS bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are encountering is caused by the fact that, by default, the `background` will have the same dimensions as the content within that `View`.
You can use the following modifier on the View, before setting the background, so that it will take the full available `width` and `height`, and so will the `background`.

```swift
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

`.ignoresSafeArea()` in the other end doesn't help because it tells the `View` to ignore the safe area layout guides, and in your specific case there are **no safe areas** to respect.

Official SwiftUI `frame` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/presentedwindowcontent/frame(minwidth:idealwidth:maxwidth:minheight:idealheight:maxheight:alignment:))

Comment: Awesome, works! Any idea how to get rid of the flashing?